# How can I config CocoaPods to use https://github.com/RestKit/cocoa-oauth instead of the    outdated one?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, automatic-ref-counting, restkit

In a newly created Xcode project with ARC enabled, there are warning messages in `RKRequest.m`:

```
Semantic Issue:
Instance method '-hostAndPort' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
Semantic Issue:
Class method '+URLRequestForPath:PUTParameters:scheme:host:consumerKey:consumerSecret:accessToken:tokenSecret:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
Semantic Issue:
Instance method '-hostAndPort' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
Semantic Issue:
Class method '+URLRequestForPath:POSTParameters:scheme:host:consumerKey:consumerSecret:accessToken:tokenSecret:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
Semantic Issue:
Instance method '-hostAndPort' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

Here is the `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios

dependency 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '1.2'
dependency 'RestKit', '0.10.1'
```

with:

```
cocoapods (0.6.0.rc2)
```

How can the warnings be fixed?

**UPDATE:**

After further investigation, it seems that CocoaPods depends on a out-dated `cocoa-oauth` library, which is described [in this issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/issues/246). So the question becomes:

- How can I config CocoaPods to use https://github.com/RestKit/cocoa-oauth instead of the
  outdated one?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about cocoapods, but I do know about your warnings.  Those warnings mean that the messages that you are trying to send the objects are not found in the header.

This can mean a few things:

```
- the header file is not in the search path of your build settings. 
- the header file does not exist.
- the header file is not included in your project.
- the methods do not exist at all or do not exist in your header.
```

Make sure that you are importing the RKRequest.h file and that is in the search path.  Remember, if RKRequest.m is apart of a framework or library your project still needs the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .m source

```
#import < RestKit/RestKit.h >
```

and lib to your project

See related

[RestKit/RestKit.h file not found error - version 0.10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168610/restkit-restkit-h-file-not-found-error-version-0-10-0)